# Как связать html фалый в Spring

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Учусь Spring и столкнулся с проблемой подключения одного html файла к другому.
Тэг html выглядит так

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Главная страница</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div th:insert="header :: header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<div th:fragment="header">
    <header class="site-header sticky-top py-1">
        <nav class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between">
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Tour</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Product</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Enterprise</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Support</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Cart</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из `header.html` файла вклучится только часть помеченная `th:fragment` (Run time). Сам файл должен/может быть корректным HTML файлом. Это дает возможность использовать файл статически (Design time). Просто открыть его в броузере. Больше можно почитать здесь: [Including template fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments) Например...

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>fragment</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="header">
    <header class="site-header sticky-top py-1">
        <nav class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between">
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Tour</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Product</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Enterprise</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Support</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="py-2 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">Cart</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: То есть мне надо каждый раз к каждому HTML  будет писать свой header?
Просто сделал по вашему примеру у меня просто добавилась новая страница.
А на главной странице нету header

Comment: Нет, вы будете его включать `<div th:insert="header :: header"></div>`.  Что значит на главной странице нет `header`, вы же его включили . Вы аппликашон то запустили? Две разные вещи посмотреть на главную страничку с файловой системы или по URL сервера который вы запустили. `Thymeleaf` работает на сервере а не в броузере.

Comment: Вот нашел [пример](https://leodev.ru/blog/spring-security/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-example) страничек на русском. Посмотрите как там выглядят странички. Каждая корректный HTML код, но каждая из них, когда запущена на сервере, будет включённой или будет включать в себя другие странички